# Which site for a question about my child's writing from a psychological standpoint?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

> In April 2017, My younger left the house without informing anyone. It was very hot summer here in India. Whole afternoon, he walked alone. When he left he took no money, no phone and anything. Somehow, When we got him back he told us that "I left home searching the god".
>
> After few days, we told him to write about his feelings, why he left and how is he feeling now. I will attach the image of his writing. He is 16 years old.

Our psychologist told he is suffering from Schizo thought disorder. I want professional opinion based on his writing.

On which site should I post this question?

Comment: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/

Comment: On no site here will you get a "professional opinion".  You will get opinions by random people you don't know on the internet.  Get a second opinion from another psychologist.  Don't risk your son's health on what some internet goofball says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Stack Exchange site offers *professional opinions*, as such. Most SE sites *do* have opinions from professionals, including very likely mental health professionals on CogSci or Health. Unfortunately, those are far from the only opinions they gather, and there's no specific way to distinguish, other than one's own personal discernment. Health, Law, and other sites have a disclaimer that they do not and cannot offer *professional opinions*, medical/attorney confidentiality, or anything similar.

For those, you really need to see an actual professional, with an actual physical location, that has a legal and social responsibility to a specific area. For your particular case, getting a second opinion from another psychiatrist is not a bad idea, but getting a "second opinion" from teh intarwebs is highly likely to be counterproductive.

Comment: Health and Law, in particular, have specific close reasons for questions that are requests for professional advice.